# I am trying to delete unused files from my linux machine but I am getting EOF errors and unexpected end of file errors

Tags: bash

Ok I'm new to this stuff but essentially I've been handed a bloated Linux machine and I want to pare down some old and unused files I've created a script for this but since I'm new I only have a vague idea of what I'm doing and I keep getting persistent errors I don't have the answer too.

This is the script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

OLD=30

EMPTY=1

#These two variables store what is considered old or unused.

echo "Do you want to change the variables if so enter y if not press n

read Q1

if $Q1="y"

        echo "Do you wish to change the age at what is considered old or the size of the file you need to be at or under to be considered unused if it is the first 1 press 1 if it is the later enter 2"
        
read Q2
        
if $Q2="1"
                
echo "please enter the time in days you wish for things to be c~onsidered old:"
                
read Q3
                
OLD=$Q3
                
fi
        
elif $Q2="2"
                echo "please enter the size in megabytes you wish for things to be considered unused"
                
read Q4
                
EMPTY=$Q4
                
fi

find / -type f -atime +$OLD -atime -100000000000000000 -size +$EMPTYM -size -100000000000000000000000000000M
```

And frankly its breaking so much I'm probably going to do this by ls -l at this point.

Comment: You have significant syntax errors that will prevent the script from running (e.g. `if $Q1="y"` should be `if [ "$Q1" = "y" ]; then`) Suggest you paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix the basic syntax issues, then post the updated question here. Otherwise it's basically a fix my script question. (a bit overbroad)

Comment: Also, randomly deleting “old” files from everywhere in `/` is likely to result in a very broken system. Many essential system files may not have been changed since installation.